# Sequelize transactional tests

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible to wrap each sequelize test in a transaction and rollback at the end of each test? Which would be the recommended way to implement this with sequelize?

Also would it work if the code under test is also opening a transaction?(nested transactions)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Sequelize supports nested transactions.

It sounds like you're attempting to maintain isolation between tests so that changes in one test don't affect another. My team accomplishes this by populating the test database with fixture data in a `beforeEach` declaration and truncating affected tables in an `afterEach` declaration. The tests run fairly quickly using this method.

To keep the tests running efficiently, you can narrow the focus of your cleanup step and configure per `describe` block to only truncate the handful of tables affected by each block of tests. For example, if you are testing your `User` model, add an `afterEach` to that file that will only truncate the `User` table.

Comment: We are also using that approach. The reason for wrapping the tests in a transaction is for preventing us to truncate all tables to clean the db in every test. As our test suite is quite big and we have identified the truncation to be the part taking the most time in each test.

Comment: Perhaps you are already doing this, but you could try narrowing the focus of your cleanup step and configure per `describe` block to only truncate the handful of tables affected by each block of tests. For example, if you are testing your `User` model, add an `afterEach` to that file that will only truncate the `User` table.

Comment: You should add this to your answer, John, as I believe this is the crux of what user1990009 was in need of. Thank you.

Comment: Any modern answer to this for recent sequelize versions?

Comment: Sequelize *does* support nested transactions. It will set a save point if you call sequelize.transaction with an exiting transaction object inside the option argument.

I think the key is some clever mixture of cls-hooked so that your code will try to find an existing transaction from a cls-hooked namespace, and use that instead of creating a brand new transaction. However I have yet to figure out how to use cls-hooks correctly, especially in the context of writing Mocha tests.